# Android: how to set item checked in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

Is there a way to check an element in a `gridview`?

I cannot find the `toggle()` method or `setChecked(true)`, my `gridview` has an adapter that extends BaseAdapter and I want to change background color when an element is checked (not only selected).

I would do like ListView: `GridView.setChoicheMode(MULTICHOICE)` and then `item.toggle()` or `item.setChecked(true)` and store the state of check into the view.

**Edit:**

I added an empty `CheckedTextView` to store the check state. 
But is there a cleaner way to do this?

**Edit2**
Now I can do what I want but when i scroll down the gridview and then I scroll up the selected items aren't selected anymore.

```
boolean checked = layout.getCheckedItemPositions().get(position);
                if(checked){
                    check.toggle();
                    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
                }
                else{
                    check.toggle();
                    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
                }
```

where layout is the layout of the gridview.
I think I have to modify the getView method of my adapter, but this code does not works:

```
CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txv_grid_check);
        boolean checked = check.isChecked();
        if(checked){
            layout.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        }
        else{
            layout.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
```

**Edit 3**

I think there is no way to do what I want (store the state in the CheckedTextView element) because the views are destroyed and recreated when scrolling a list or a gridview. So I needed to handle the state of the items into the adapter. I used an HashSet of int to store the position of the checked items and I made some public method for handle this list from the gridview.
In the gridview activity it is possibile to get the adapter and then do myadapter.check(int position) or uncheck(int position).
Then in the adapter, into the getView() method, we need to check if a position is in the list and set the appropriate background color.

Comment: use selector xmls for background to show selected pressed states.

Comment: Add more clarification in your question.

Comment: @AdilSoomro this can be a solution. Now I'm doing it dinamically

Comment: do you want to set one item at a time or multiple items ?

Comment: @Rajesh multiple items. Now I can do what i want but when I scroll the gridview the state of the item seems to be lost

Comment: just have a look of my code . and use it.. if you scroll it position of selected item wont get change.

Comment: @Rajesh If I understand you implemented the behaviour of the checked state, but I would use the builtin methods

Comment: built in method means ? like GridView.setChoicheMode(MULTICHOICE) ???

Comment: @Rajesh I used it, but now I don't know how to handle the state of the items in the adapter, avoiding to do it manually..

Comment: i am not getting you.. exactly.

Comment: @Rajesh from the gridview i can use
    layout.setItemChecked(position, true);    check.setChecked(true); 
but in the adapter I have to handle a list o something with position of checked items, so I can change the background color in getView() method. I would not implement everything by myself..

Comment: @Rajesh I marked Nagaraj436 answers as correct because I think is more generic and simple, but your can work well too. Thank you for support.

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/multichoiceadapter/) may be this helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328006/1649309) will help you. Here in this example there is TextView in grid item layout, which you change to a CheckedTextView or a Checkbox. In the getView() check the state and set the Background Color of your Grid item.

Comment: I would not to implement this, I would a standard way to do this, like lists.

Comment: That answer is a hack. I have added an answer where I describe more standard way how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17389893/1200812

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. it works well for me.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

             final MyDat mydat;// = new MyDat();
            if (position >= MyViewedMeItemList.size()) {
                mydat = new MyDat();

            } 
            else
            {
                mydat = MyViewedMeItemList.get(position);
            }

            mydat.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
            mydat.artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
            mydat.duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
            mydat.thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
            mydat.cccheckbomx=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.rajesh);        
            mydat.cccheckbomx.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            if (mydat.myCheckStatus) {
                // Toast.makeText(MessageInboxDelete.this, "true --->" +
                // position,
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mydat.cccheckbomx.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                /*
                 * Toast.makeText(MessageInboxDelete.this, "false --->" +
                 * position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 */
                mydat.cccheckbomx.setChecked(false);
            }

           mydat.cccheckbomx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View paramView) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Rajesh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                    int gridchild;
                    gridchild = list.getChildCount();
                    for (int j = 0; j < gridchild; j++) {
                        // DrawArea_Steptwo.gridview.getChildAt(j);

                    //  Toast.makeText(context, "Rajesh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        RelativeLayout gridchildlayout = (RelativeLayout) list
                                .getChildAt(j);

                        CheckBox tempRadioToggle = (CheckBox) gridchildlayout
                                .findViewById(R.id.rajesh);

                        tempRadioToggle.setChecked(false);                    

                        MyDat tempViewholder = MyViewedMeItemList.get(j);
                        tempViewholder.myCheckStatus = false;
                    }


                    for(int j = 0; j < MyViewedMeItemList.size(); j++) {
                        MyDat tempViewholder = MyViewedMeItemList.get(j);
                        tempViewholder.myCheckStatus = false;
                    }
                    CheckBox tempRadioToggle = (CheckBox) paramView.findViewById(R.id.rajesh);      
                    tempRadioToggle.setChecked(true);

                    MyDat tempViewholder = MyViewedMeItemList.get(position);

                            if (tempViewholder.myCheckStatus == false) {
                                tempViewholder.myCheckStatus = true;
                                // tempViewholder.deleteRadioButton.setChecked(true);


                            } else {
                                tempViewholder.myCheckStatus = false;
                                // tempViewholder.deleteRadioButton.setChecked(false);

                            }


                }
            });
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song = data.get(position);

            // Setting all values in listview
            mydat.title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
            mydat.artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
            mydat.duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), mydat.thumb_image);

            if (MyViewedMeItemList.size() <= position) {
                MyViewedMeItemList.add(mydat);
            }



            return vi;
        }

     public  class MyDat{

           Boolean myCheckStatus=false;
           TextView title ;
           TextView artist;
           TextView duration;
           ImageView thumb_image;
           CheckBox cccheckbomx;

       }
    }
```

Comment: You can use GridView to do the checking for you - no onCLickListener required, you don't have to store the state yourself, you don't have to update the visual appearance yourself. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17389893/1200812