# gridview change item background by position in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-gridview, baseadapter

I have Custom `BaseAdapter`. Which i used in my `GridView` . I trying to change Item background color by position(also i change Textview's text color)
this is a my `baseadapter` source

```
public class ServiciesGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

private List<ServicesListItem> itemList;

public ServiciesGridAdapter(Context context, List<ServicesListItem> mobileValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemList = mobileValues;

}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View gridView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        gridView = new View(context);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_servisies_gridview_items, null);

        final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) gridView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_items_layout);


        final TextView serviciesID = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.servicies_grid_id);
        final TextView serviciesName = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.servicies_grid_name);
        serviciesID.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        serviciesName.setText(itemList.get(position).getIdentifier() + " EUR");



        mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corners_blue);
                serviciesID.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                serviciesName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


            }
        });

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


}
```

when i run my app in item click i can change background color, but when i checked another item,first item's background  is a same. Simply, i want to change only one items background each click.

How i can solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to reset all other view text color and background, so make a loop and do it.. try below code

```
    mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i=0;i<parent.getChildCount();i++){
            View c = parent.getChildAt(i);
            c.findViewById(R.id.gridview_items_layout).setBackgroundResource(defaultResource);
            (TextView) c.findViewById(R.id.servicies_grid_id).setTextColor(defaultColor);
            ((TextView) c.findViewById(R.id.servicies_grid_name)).setTextColor(defaultColor);
        }
        mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corners_blue);
        serviciesID.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        serviciesName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


    }
});
```

Comment: i tryed it but i have one problem. background changed but Textview's textcolor always is white .defaultColor now working in textview

Comment: what default color you used on textView??

Comment: use this setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

Comment: @ Deepak i have one broblem. when i selected(changed) items background color and scroll my gridview some item's background also changed

Comment: do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> use of [listSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector) for change item background by position in gridview ..

add color you `color.xml`

```
<resources>
 <color name="onClickColor">#FFFFFF</color>  
</resources>
```

add `selecter.xml` to `drawable` folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item 
     android:state_pressed="true"
     android:drawable="@color/onClickColor">
 </item>
</selector>
```

add `listSelector` to your `GridView`

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selecter">
</GridView>
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14375118/2553431) post...

Comment: will this also change the color of the textView?

Comment: he stated that he want to change item background he clicks ... obviously it will change gridvew index background ... so textview color should be contrast to that...